# Qt: Setting up buttons on a splash screen

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have a splash screen set up like so, (the QApplication was declared earlier):

```
QSplashScreen *splash = new QSplashScreen;
splash->setPixmap( QPixmap("image.png" ) );
splash->show();
```

What I would like to know ifs if there is a way in Qt that allows buttons to be attached to the splash screen. I would like to have some sort of user interaction on the splash screen itself.

Comment: [QSplashScreen](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplashscreen.html) inherits from `QWidget`. A `QWidget` can host other `QWidget`s.

Answer (score 0):

Since [`QSplashScreen`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplashscreen.html) class inherits from `QWidget` class, you probably can access the most of capabilities a `QWidget` provides e.g. adding child widgets.

However, you should be aware of the following notice pointed to by [the doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplashscreen.html#details).

> Since the splash screen is typically displayed before the event loop has started running, it is necessary to periodically call `QApplication::processEvents()` to receive the mouse clicks.

Therefore after registering the click event of that button you should periodically call `QApplication::processEvents()` or (`qApp->processEvents()`) during your app initialization to allow the app to handle click events.